# How to fit 2nd order polynomial to multiple graphs and show them together?

Tags: plotting, import

I want to fit 2<sup>nd</sup> order polynomial to multiple graphs and show them together;
I imported file by using following command:

```
Mode1 = Import["1-CF.txt", "Table"];
```

Then, I plot each as following

```
PM20 = Mode1[[All, {1, 2}]];

PM21 = Mode1[[All, {1, 3}]];
```

Then, I make fit to each by using:

```
FPM20 = Fit[PM20, {1, x, x^2}, x]

FPM21 = Fit[PM21, {1, x, x^2}, x]
```

(I need these equations too, because further I need to have differential on each polynomial fit, which is I am doing by:)

```
DFPM20 = D[FPM20, {x, 1}][[1]];

DFPM21 = D[FPM21, {x, 1}][[1]];
```

I want to make all this process elegant. So far, I have been able to show all plots by single command:

```
plotlist = Table[
  ListLinePlot[Mode1[[All, {1, i}]]]
  , {i, 2, Dimensions[Mode1[[2]]}
 ]
```

Now, I want to fit and show polynomial fit together.

Comment: Have a look at [Show](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html).

Comment: Using [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) and indentation makes the code on your question more readable.

Comment: Thank you @rhermans for pointing out. I will keep this in my mind for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate[Fit[Mode1[[All, {1, #}]], {1, x, x^2}, x] & /@ {2, 3}], {x, 0, 5}], 
ListPlot[Mode1[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}]]
```

[image]

You may also add the derivatives:

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate[Fit[Mode1[[All, {1, #}]], {1, x, x^2}, x] & /@ {2, 3}], {x, 0, 5}], 
Plot[Evaluate[D[Fit[Mode1[[All, {1, #}]], {1, x, x^2}, x], x] & /@ {2, 3}], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Brown}],
ListPlot[Mode1[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks, its works perfectly, can I show in table form separately for each column(FPM20, FPM21)?

Comment: Hi, I worked it out; Table[Show[
  Plot[Evaluate[
    Fit[Mode1[[All, {1, i}]], {1, x, x^2}, x] & /@ {i}], {x, -3, 3}], 
  Plot[Evaluate[
    D[Fit[Mode1[[All, {1, i}]], {1, x, x^2}, x], x] & /@ {i}], {x, -3,
     3}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Brown}], 
  ListPlot[Mode1[[All, {1, i}]] & /@ {i}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}]], {i, 2, Dimensions[Mode1][[2]]}]